# Windows 10 won't boot up - no operating system found

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

A couple of days ago Windows stopped booting up. Startup repair did not fix the problem.

I tried to follow the instructions on [this page](https://www.niallbrady.com/2021/09/26/fixing-total-identified-windows-installations-0/), among many others. I mention this one because it seemed to get me the closest to success.

> I googled and found the following suggestions.
>
> Bootrec /fixmbr
>
> Bootrec /fixboot (Note: If this fails with access denied try BOOTSECT
> /NT60 SYS and then issue the command again)
>
> Bootrec /scanos
>
> Bootrec /rebuildbcd
>
> The problem however, is that after issuing Bootrec /rebuildbcd it
> stated
>
> ```
> “Total identified Windows installations: 0”
> ```

Like the author of this blog post, I also got this 0 installations message.

Following his later instructions, I used diskpart to find and mount the system volume with a drive letter. Then I found efi\microsoft\boot and

> attrib bcd -s -h -r
> ren bcd bcd.old
> bootrec /RebuildBcd

And it returned

> Scanning all disks for Windows installations.
>
> Please wait, since this may take a while...
>
> Successfully scanned Windows installations.  Total identified Windows
> installations: 1 [1](https://www.niallbrady.com/2021/09/26/fixing-total-identified-windows-installations-0/) D:\Windows  Add installation to boot list?
> Yes/No/All

So I say yes, reboot, and nothing has changed. I still get a 'no valid boot device' message.

How can I get my windows installation to boot again? Are there additional steps I need to take?

Comment: Nope. Backup and reinstall.  Test the main drive for hardware errors.

Comment: Ok - but how can I get insight into how it happened? It's a new SSD and all the files are still there - I only installed Windows on it a couple of weeks ago. If I don't find out why it happened, it could happen again at any time

Comment: Hard to know:   Registry changes, legacy software, some operational error.  Still test the SSD in case it had an early death.

Comment: After re-installation, use [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) (or another such product) to examine the SMART attributes of the disk, to see if the problem was hardware, meaning that the disk is faulty. If you get disk errors while installing Windows, the disk needs to be replaced.